# How to convert Laravel views to static HTML and serve them from cache?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I would like to setup functionality to transform the views in Laravel 5.3 to static HTML and serve it to visitors untill specified from a CMS call. I also like to use HTTP headers to cache the pages on a visitors computer.

1. How can i get views to be served as static HTML with route caching enabled?
2. How can i serve the static HTML views from the users cache using HTTP headers?
3. Are there any other caveats or performance boosting tricks i can/should utilise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will answer the `File based cache` with the code. Which is not exactly the `HTML` cache, but performs well.

Look at my Laravel Installation /var/www/ea (This is my Laravel Installation directory)

[image: Inside storage/framework/cache you will find the cached files]

**Step 1:** How to create cache

**Step 2:** This step comes before step 1, which is `configure` cache to `file` cache. Open the `config/cache.php` and do check two things

`'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),`  //It means your cache default driver is File based.

Then

`'path' => storage_path('framework/cache'),` //This is the path My screenshot is showing above.

**Step 3:** Lets write the code to create cache.
Open your Controller method and write following

```
\Cache::put( 'cachekey', 'Hello I am Abdul', 1 ); // 1- minute
```

[laravel documentation for cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache)

**Step 4:** Check for any new directory created inside `framework/cache/`

That's your cache file.

```
// Following code check if the cache key already exists before creating, 
// otherwise create cache file
if (Cache::has('key')){
    Cache::get('key');
} else {
    Cache::put('key', $values, 10);
}
```

Comment: Can't we store the entire rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple Package for that which you can do. It will easily cache responses as static files on disk for lightning fast page loads.

Here is the [Page Cache Package for Laravel](https://github.com/JosephSilber/page-cache)